# Spaghetti Western with a blind man

Tags: identify-this-movie, western

I'm looking for a movie. It is a western, the main character is blind and it's a really good shooter. The man is in his 50s and is dressed in black. His finally battle is in a church with the noise of the bells and dynamite.

(It is not the "Blindman" with Ringo Star.)

Comment: could it be blind justice ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_Justice_(1994_film)

Comment: @Dredd - Didn't see your comment until after I posted my answer. If you make yours an answer I'll delete mine.

Comment: nah.. its alright. yours is quite good as it is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could be [**Blind Justice**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109294/) *(1994)*:

> [image: VHS] <sup>[Source](http://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-445067281-furor-ciego-blind-justice-armand-assante-robert-davi-vhs-_JM)</sup>
>
> ... **a western about a blind gunfighter roaming the range with a baby in tow.**
>
> The enigmatic Canaan *(Armand Assante)* is a serape-clad vision in black, first glimpsed carrying a swaddled infant through Monument Valley
>
> [...]
>
> He gets sidetracked in a one-horse town, where a small band of federal cavalry is holed up guarding a ton of silver bullion. Meanwhile, evil bandit leader Alacran *(Robert Davi)* controls the only road out of town, , and has so far foiled all their attempts to send for help.
>
> [...]
>
> But **Canaan surreptitiously outfits the casket with explosives, and manages to blow casket, church, and outlaw crew sky-high.** Canaan loses his hearing in the blast, but he's able to identify Alacran by smell, and dispatches him in a final showdown.
>
> [[Source](http://movies.tvguide.com/blind-justice/review/130360)]

- [**Watch the trailer**](http://www.videodetective.com/movies/blind-justice/5155)

Comment: yeah!!! thanks a lot! i was looking for it for 10 years